# Manually starting new transaction while another transaction is active

Tags: jpa, transactions, ejb

I want to do below steps while already in active transaction

1. insert/update some records
2. select all those records hold it in memory with non entity copy
3. rollback first step without rolling back parent transaction
4. return result from step 2.

I have this

```
@Stateless
public class DBWorker {

    public Result doWork(boolean isPreview) {
        Result result;

        if(isPreview) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
        }
        doSomeWork();
        List<SomeEntity> resultOfDoSomeWork = em.createQuery(..).getResultList();
        result = copyToNonEntity(resultOfDoSomeWork);

        if(isPreview)
            em.getTransaction().rollback();

        return result;
    }
}
```

But gives exception `A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
   IllegalStateException:A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()`

Comment: Have you played around with the different transaction modes as described e.g. in the JEE 7 Tutorial (applicable for JEE 6 as well): https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/transactions003.htm#BNCIJ

Comment: I have only tried using `@TransactionAttribute`. But in this case time I'm required to do it manually.

Comment: Now, if I look at the code again, if the `copyToNonEntity` really does clone the entity objects, all values should be independent of any entity object state. Hence, the rollback should NOT affect the result objects. What exactly does not work in your code, then?

Comment: `A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()
   IllegalStateException:A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()`

Comment: Looks like you are using container managed transactions after all. Try to create two methods with different `@Transaction` annotations. One, where you use the surrounding transaction (no annotation needed), one - let's call it `getPreviewResults` -  with `RequiresNew` and throw an exception inside of that method to force the rollback.

Comment: You could use EJBContext.setRollbackOnly method to mark transaction for rollback.

Comment: That would rollback everything right? even previous work done by other EJBs inside that transaction.

Comment: That's why DaDaDom suggested using RequiresNew for this one. This will suspend the first transaction and create a new one for your method. This will be rolled back eventually but after the method returns the original transaction is left intact.

Comment: Can I manually switch between `REQUIRES` and `REQUIRES_NEW` in runtine?

Comment: to avoid copying same code into two different methods

Comment: @DulguunLst No, you cannot dynamically change transaction types, but you can have two methods annotated differently that trivially call a common method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to annotate your EJB method with the `@TransactionAttribute` Annotation.

In particular, you have to do something like this:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void myMethod() {
   // do something
}
```

`REQUIRES_NEW` indicates that a new transaction has to be started for the business method.

*Pay attention to call the method to another EJB because if you call it from the same one the new transaction will not be created.*

## ROLLBACK

You can roll back the container-managed transaction:

1. Throwing a RuntimeException: the container will automatically roll back the transaction.
2. Throwing a custom Exception annotated by `@ApplicationException(rollback=true)`:
3. By invoking the `setRollbackOnly` method of the `EJBContext` interface: forces the container to rollback the transaction, also if there is no exception.

**For example:**

*Throwing a RuntimeException:*

```
try {    
   // do something
} catch(SQLException e) {
   throw new EJBException();    
}
```

*Throwing a custom Exception:*

```
try {
   // do something
} catch(SQLException e) {
   throw new MyCustomException();
}
```

where MyCustomException class is something like:

```
@ApplicationException(rollback=true)
public class MyCustomException extends Exception {
   // your custom methods
}
```

*By invoking setRollbackOnly the method:*

```
Context.setRollbackOnly();
```

Comment: if `setRollBackOnly` is called inside that `myMethod()` will it rollback only the new transaction

Comment: Correct, the global bean transaction will remain unaffected if `myMethod()` will throws an Exception